# Cannot get spray-json dependency to work in play project

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have spent countless hours trying to get spray json to be included as a dependency in my play project built on scala 2.10.

Can someone provide definitive explanation for the EXACT magical incantions to use in the project files for this thing?!!!!

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    val appName         = "linscot"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      jdbc,
      anorm,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
      "com.cloudphysics" % "jerkson_2.10" % "0.6.3",

      //"cc.spray.json" % "spray-json_2.9.1" %"1.0.1"
      "io.spray" %  "spray-json_2.10.1" % "1.2.5"
    )


    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(   
      // Add your own project settings here   

        //libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"


    )
}
```

getting this:

```
[info] Updating {file:/Users/Joel/Projects/linscot-server/}linscot...
[warn]  module not found: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Joel/.ivy2/local/io.spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     :: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5: not found
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5: not found
[warn] some of the dependencies were not recompiled properly, so classloader is not avaialable
[info] Updating {file:/Users/Joel/Projects/linscot-server/}linscot...
[warn]  module not found: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Joel/.ivy2/local/io.spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/spray-json_2.10.1/1.2.5/spray-json_2.10.1-1.2.5.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     :: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5: not found
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#spray-json_2.10.1;1.2.5: not found
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? 2.1.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for spray-json dependency is:

```
"io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"
```

Using `%%` ensures you get the right version for the version of Scala you are using.

Spray doesn't use one of the default repositories for distribution of the library, so you also have to specify that one. The settings with that then become:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(   
    resolvers += "spray" at "http://repo.spray.io/",
    libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I'm new to play, scala and sbt and this build config syntax threw me.  I'm hoping to replace jerkson and have spray json also handle nested objects as jerkson did.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when i couldn't get the spray-json dependency in version 1.3.2 working in my project. The sbt.last.log was telling me: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#spray-json_2.11;1.3.2: not found.
It turned out that spray-json artifact in version 1.3.2 is simply not available in http://repo.spray.io repository. The solution is to use version 1.3.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use spray json in standalone test project, but was facing similar error.

```
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.4"
```

from https://github.com/spray/spray-json was not helpful.

Adding below dependency from https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html didn't give any error.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.1.11"
```